# iPhone View methods

Tags: iphone, methods, view, viewdidload

Please tell me the step by step different view methods of iOS. Please explain which method is executed first etc.I means to say that which method executed when?

Answer (score 3):

1. Init or InitWithCode or InitWithNibName or (any initialization method)
2. loadView                ///it only called when you have custom viewController and you load custom view instead from nibFile, normally loadView do not called
3. viewDidLoad
4. viewWillAppear
5. viewDidAppear

on unload side

1. viewWillDisappear
2. viewDidDisappear
3. viewDidUnload
4. dealloc

These specific to viewController only not for tableView or other type of viewController. If I am missing any method plz add comments.

Comment: Each of these methods must make the same call to `super` and in the right way, otherwise you'll be in an infinite loop. The methods that create or show something call super first, and then do whatever. The methods that remove a view make the call to super last. For example, the first line of `viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated` should be `[super viewWillAppear:animate]`, whereas the last line of `viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated` needs to be `[super viewWillDisappear:animated]`. The latter is like calling `[super dealloc]` in the last line of your own `dealloc` methods.

Comment: An easy way to convince yourself of the order in which they're called is to do `NSLog(@"will load")`, `NSLog(@"did load")`, `NSLog(@"will appear")`, ... , NSLog(@"dealloc") in each and see what's what from the console.

Comment: Thanx waqas.. Hw r u? thnx for ur views.

Answer (score 0):

For your specific question, you should add the subview in viewDidLoad. Because, if you overwrite the loadView, you have to do all the jobs, loading all the views.

Here is the explanation from [Apple's documentation:](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

The steps that occur during the load cycle are as follows:

```
1.

  * Some part of your application asks for the view in the view

controller’s view property.

2.

  * If the view is not currently in memory, the view controller calls its loadView

method.

3.

  * The loadView method does one of the following:

        If you override this method, your implementation is

responsible for creating all necessary views and assigning a non-nil value to the view property.

        If you do not override this method, the default implementation uses 

the nibName and nibBundle properties of the view controller to try to load the view from the specified nib file. If the specified nib file is not found, it looks for a nib file whose name matches the name of the view controller class and loads that file.

        If no nib file is available, the method creates an empty UIView object 

and assigns it to the view property.

4.

  * The view controller calls its viewDidLoad method to perform any

additional load-time tasks.
```